# Urn Problem-Determining the Transition Probability Matrix

Tags: markov-chains, markov-process, stochastic-analysis

I have two urns A and B containing a total of N balls.  An experiment is performed where a ball is selected at random (all selections equally likely) at time t(t=1,2,...) from the totality of N balls.  Then an urn is selected at random (A is chosen at probability p and B at probability q) and the ball previously drawn is placed in this urn.  The state of the system at each trial is represented by the number of balls in A.  How would I determine the transition probability matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p_{ij}$ be the probability that we go to state $j$ from $i$.

Suppose we are in state $i$. There are three cases:
The state increases by $1$, decreases by $1$ or stays the same.

The state decreases by $1$ if and only if we draw a ball from $A$ and place it into $B$. The probability for that is $\frac{i}{N}q$. Similarly the probability that the state increases by $1$ is $\frac{N-i}{N}p$. So

$p_{ij} = \begin{cases} \frac{N-i}{N}p & j=i+1\\\frac{i}{N}q & j=i-1\\1- \frac{N-i}{N}p-\frac{i}{N}q &j=i\\0&\text{otherwise} \end{cases}$